# Pivot Function on Multiple Tables and Dynamic Columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have 3 tables in `Table 2` we have columns with `columnName` Field they can grow Dynamically at that time we have just 5 columns for Each `CTypeId` they can be 6 or 10 etc.  In `Table3` we have the column values.

For example `AccountManager` From `Table 2` have value in `Table 3` `Jack / Kate`
similarly other columns and their values are

```
ColumnName |  Values
Channel    |  PS
StartDate  |  06/03/2017
```

[image]

I want Result Like this

[image]

I have tried using Pivot Function with the following query:

```
Declare @Columns nvarchar(max) 
Declare @a nvarchar(max)
Set @Columns = (select STUFF((select ',' + '[' + Convert(varchar(200), ColumnName) + ']' from CharityTypeInformationDynamicFields FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1, ''))

    Declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
       = 'Select * 
          from
          (select cd.Id, cd.Value, ci.ColumnName 
           from Table3 cd 
           Inner Join Table2         ci 
               on ci.Id = cd.DynamicFieldID
          ) as s 
          Pivot(MAX(Value) ForColumnName IN ('+@columns+')) as pvt'
    Select @sql
```

But the query gives the result:

[image]

What do I need to change to achieve my desired output?

Comment: Change the `Select * from` in your final pivot query to only include the column that you actually need. You've got `cd.Id` in your subquery which is most likely skewing the final result because you're grouping by it.

Comment: No effect on my Result.. :(

Comment: If you print `@sql`, what is it showing that your final query?

Comment: Select [Account Manager],[Channel],[Start Date],[End Date],[Gross Annual] from (
select cd.Id, cd.Value, ci.ColumnName from Table3 cd Inner Join Table2 ci on ci.Id = cd.DynamicFieldID) as s 
Pivot
(MAX(Value) For
ColumnName IN ([Account Manager],[Channel],[Start Date],[End Date],[Gross Annual])
) as pvt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few issues that you need to solve in order to get the result you desire.  But before trying a dynamic sql version of a query I'd always recommend that you try get your final result by writing a hard-coded or static version first. This allows you to get the desired result without bugs and then convert it to dynamic sql as your final query.

First, let's get your table structures and sample data into a reusable script. It appears that you only need `table2` and `table3` to get your end result:

```
create table #table2
(
  id int,
  ctypeid int,
  columnname varchar(50)
)

insert into #table2
values
(1, 20, 'Account Manager'), (2, 20, 'Channel'),
(3, 20, 'Start Date'), (4, 20, 'End Date'),
(5, 20, 'Gross Annual'), (6, 6, 'Account Manager'),
(7, 6, 'Channel'), (8, 6, 'Start Date'),
(9, 6, 'End Date'), (10, 6, 'Gross Annual');

create table #table3
(
  id int,
  table2id int,
  value varchar(50)
)

insert into #table3
values
(1, 1, 'Jack / Kate'), (2, 2, 'PS'), (3, 3, '06/03/2017'), 
(4, 4, '07/03/2017'), (5, 5, '2500'), (6, 6, 'Ollie'), 
(7, 7, 'D2D'), (8, 8, '06/03/2017'), (9, 9, '06/03/2017'), 
(10, 10, '5232'), (11, 1, 'Jack'), (12, 2, 'PSP'), 
(13, 3, '06/03/2017'), (14, 4, '07/03/2017'), (15, 5, '7000'),
(16, 1, 'Jack Sparrow'), (17, 2, 'PS Sparrow'), (1, 3, '06/03/2017'), 
(19, 4, '07/03/2017'), (20, 5, '3000'), (21, 6, 'John'), 
(22, 7, 'JEDF'), (23, 8, '06/03/2017'), (24, 9, '06/03/2017'), 
(25, 10, '5232');
```

Next, you need to write your `PIVOT` query.  Your final result only includes the values from 3 columns `CTypeId`, `Value`, and `ColumnName`, so the start of your query PIVOT would be:

```
select 
  CTypeId,
  [Account Manager], [Channel], [Start Date], 
  [End Date], [Gross Annual]
from 
(
   select ci.CTypeId, cd.Value, ci.ColumnName
   from #Table3 cd 
   Inner Join #Table2 ci 
     on ci.Id = cd.Table2Id
) d
pivot
(
  max(Value)
  for ColumnName in ([Account Manager], [Channel], [Start Date], 
                      [End Date], [Gross Annual])
) piv
```

[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/641653). But since you're aggregating string values in the `Value` column, you will only return one row for each `CTypeId`:

```
+---------+-----------------+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
| CTypeId | Account Manager | Channel | Start Date |  End Date  | Gross Annual  |
+---------+-----------------+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
|       6 | Ollie           | JEDF    | 06/03/2017 | 06/03/2017 |          5232 |
|      20 | Jack Sparrow    | PSP     | 06/03/2017 | 07/03/2017 |          7000 |
+---------+-----------------+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

which is not what you want, so you need to do something to allow for multiple rows.  If you look at a sample of the data that is returned by the subquery:

```
+---------+-------------+------------------+
| CTypeId |    Value    | ColumnName       |
+---------+-------------+------------------+
|      20 | Jack / Kate | Account Manager  |
|      20 | PS          | Channel          |
|      20 | 06/03/2017  | Start Date       |
|      20 | 07/03/2017  | End Date         |
|      20 | 2500        | Gross Annual     |
|       6 | Ollie       | Account Manager  |
|       6 | D2D         | Channel          |
|       6 | 06/03/2017  | Start Date       |
|       6 | 06/03/2017  | End Date         |
|       6 | 5232        | Gross Annual     |
+---------+-------------+------------------+
```

You'll see that you have unique data over a combination of `CTypeId` and `ColumnName` values, so you can create a unique row number using the windowing function [`row_number`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in your subquery which can be used to uniquely group the data for a pivot. By changing the above `PIVOT` code to:

```
select 
  CTypeId,
  [Account Manager], [Channel], [Start Date], 
  [End Date], [Gross Annual]
from 
(
   select ci.CTypeId, cd.Value, ci.ColumnName,
     rn = row_number() over(partition by ci.CTypeId, ci.ColumnName order by cd.Value)
   from #Table3 cd 
   Inner Join #Table2 ci 
     on ci.Id = cd.Table2Id
) d
pivot
(
  max(Value)
  for ColumnName in ([Account Manager], [Channel], [Start Date], 
                      [End Date], [Gross Annual])
) piv
order by CTypeId
```

[See demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/641657), you get the desired result:

```
+---------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
| CTypeId | Account Manager |  Channel   | Start Date |  End Date  | Gross Annual  |
+---------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
|       6 | John            | D2D        | 06/03/2017 | 06/03/2017 |          5232 |
|       6 | Ollie           | JEDF       | 06/03/2017 | 06/03/2017 |          5232 |
|      20 | Jack            | PS         | 06/03/2017 | 07/03/2017 |          2500 |
|      20 | Jack / Kate     | PS Sparrow | 06/03/2017 | 07/03/2017 |          3000 |
|      20 | Jack Sparrow    | PSP        | 06/03/2017 | 07/03/2017 |          7000 |
+---------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

Once you've got your final result you want, it's easy to convert the query to dynamic SQL:

```
Declare @Columns nvarchar(max) 
Declare @a nvarchar(max)
Set @Columns = stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(ColumnName) 
                   from #table2
                   for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

Declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
 = 'Select CTypeId, '+@Columns+'
    from
    (
      select ci.CTypeId, cd.Value, ci.ColumnName,
        rn = row_number() over(partition by  ci.CTypeId, ci.ColumnName order by cd.Value)
      from #Table3 cd 
      Inner Join #Table2         ci 
        on ci.Id = cd.Table2Id
    ) as s 
    Pivot(MAX(Value) For ColumnName IN ('+@columns+')) as pvt
    order by CTypeId'


execute(@sql);
```

[See Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/641661).  This gives the same result as the hard-coded version with the flexibility of dynamic sql.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining in detail and pointing out my faults. this is all i want.. :)